# usar json para ampliar una lista js

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

lo que quiero hacer es crear un formulario html que complete un json y a su vez complete tanto un js como un css, aunque no estoy seguro de que se pueda.
Me explico mejor, he creado un programa que al presionar un boton pasa de imagen:

```js
var bodyObj, index, classList;
index = -1;
bodyObj = document.getElementById("body");

classList = [
    'imageOne',
    'imageTwo',
    'imageThree',
    'imageFour',
    'imageFive',
    'imageSix',
    'imageSeven',
    'imageEight',
    'imageNine',
    'imageTen',
    'imageEleven',
    'imageTwelve',
    'imageThirteen',
    'imageFourteen',
    'imageFifteen',
    'imageSixteen',
    'imageSeventeen',
    'imageEighteen',
    'imageNineteen',
    'imageTwenty',
    'imageTwentyOne',
    'imageTwentyTwo',
    'imageTwentyThree',
    'imageTwentyFour',
    'imageTwentyFive',
    'imageTwentySix',
    'imageTwentySeven',
    'imageTwentyEight',
]

function updateIndex() {
    if (index === (classList.length - 1)) {
        index = 0;
    } else {
        ++index;
    }
}

function changeElements() {
    updateIndex();
    bodyObj.className = classList[index];
}

changeElements();
```

```css
#boton {
    position: absolute;top: 90vh;
}

.imageOne {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://images7.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED878/5e663a87daac5.jpeg");
}

.imageTwo {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/df/f4/13/dff413535d8f8400cbc0f086d5c06590.jpg");
}

.imageThree {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
}

.imageFour {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OHRHwy3mv8c/maxresdefault.jpg");
}

.imageFive {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://cdn.memegenerator.es/imagenes/memes/full/28/86/28860423.jpg");
}

.imageSix {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://images3.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED71/5e20e2bd4c691.jpeg");
}

.imageSeven {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d3/a2/03/d3a203ba182ab77eb0382625150fb74c.jpg");
}

.imageEight {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://images3.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED712/5f2d481d8d456.jpeg");
}

.imageNine {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://pm1.narvii.com/7619/0c3fa8c67392d0a1ee36865fb5546ce1642e280dr1-720-656v2_00.jpg");
}

.imageTen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/736x/52/ed/52/52ed5277222e57504b238f729fe210a5.jpg");
}

.imageEleven {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/9b/bd/899bbd8122995b8010f268b30dddf520.jpg");
}

.imageTwelve {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://images3.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED316/5db863834c2e5.jpeg");
}

.imageThirdteen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfCZbUixYWzoI2fNq7BYuyqlv0NqpTq7m4ZQ&usqp=CAU");
}

.imageFourteen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/e8/8f/b0e88f383d315a5cdd5df84ae30e4cbd.jpg");
}

.imageFifteen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/65w8mczm9my41.jpg");
}

.imageSixteen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/983107271289815040/GXXiPcA4_400x400.jpg");
}

.imageSeventeen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://enportada.cl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/69894320_715627375593789_7423265735340653589_n.jpg");
}

.imageEighteen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=517x1024:format=jpg/path/s2161fa004f2cb727/image/id1a75c5f4c2019c1/version/1542388804/image.jpg");
}

.imageNineteen {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://enportada.cl/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/75352136_535823540533391_890284238621815372_n.jpg");
}

.imageTwenty {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcThoEOzQ6Apae1DloLGH7JMdpzLhwr9KU4BpQ&usqp=CAU");
}

.imageTwentyOne {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/236x/0b/2e/6f/0b2e6f6fd4dcccd05cb2c607e031ca04.jpg");
}

.imageTwentyTwo {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://img.wattpad.com/cover/192718358-352-k57609.jpg");
}

.imageTwentyThree {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://images7.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED867/5c7d930d4f412.jpeg");
}

.imageTwentyFour {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5c/3d/9f/5c3d9f647018a9847f0f05c367fa897a.jpg");
}

.imageTwentyFive {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.redd.it/bn7kk7yrlun51.jpg");
}

.imageTwentySix {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzq9nRWHG_iz89rh4QXndMHDxi2AlUaK2l7A&usqp=CAU");
}

.imageTwentySeven {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://cm1.narvii.com/6728/8bd09c9f4f81b5e1059c52977a5a3c9448d66f6b_00.jpg");
}

.imageTwentyEight {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShupDbyeRRArGQO5lIPp7_p-1E5eT9_3-t6g&usqp=CAU");
}
```

```html
<body id="body" class="imageOne">
    <button id="boton" onclick="changeElements()">Cambiar Meme</button>
```

Si os dais cuenta he creado un array que contiene las clases que luego uso en el css para poner la imagen de fondo.

Por lo tanto lo que necesito es un json que amplíe el array al mismo tiempo que añade en el css la clase con el URL para colocar la imágen

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Voy a serte sincero. No sé que estás intentando hacer, pero lo estás haciendo mal. *Cómo sabes que lo estoy haciendo mal si no sabes qué estoy haciendo?* -> Pues porque si necesitas una clase para cada imagen, y no sabes exactamente cuantas imágenes vas a tener, lo estás haciendo mal. Aun más cuando todas las clases tienen exactamente el mismo contenido excepto por la URL de la imagen... lo suyo sería que cambies directamente el `background-image: url()` desde javascript, y uses una única clase!

Comment: comprendo, tiene sentido lo que dices, y como lo pongo de forma que haya un numero indefinido de imágenes que pueda poner? sin poner miles de lineas claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma mas fasil seria agregando un arreglo de urls para evitar crear tantos css.

con estos creamos una clase unica para todos y con javascript solo modificamos su propiedad `background-image` en ves de crear una clase para cada imagen como tal.

ejemplo:

```js
var bodyObj, index, memes;
index = -1;
bodyObj = document.getElementById("body");

memes = [
"https://images7.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED878/5e663a87daac5.jpeg",
"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/df/f4/13/dff413535d8f8400cbc0f086d5c06590.jpg",
"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OHRHwy3mv8c/maxresdefault.jpg",
"https://cdn.memegenerator.es/imagenes/memes/full/28/86/28860423.jpg",
"https://images3.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED71/5e20e2bd4c691.jpeg",
"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d3/a2/03/d3a203ba182ab77eb0382625150fb74c.jpg",
"https://images3.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED712/5f2d481d8d456.jpeg",
"https://pm1.narvii.com/7619/0c3fa8c67392d0a1ee36865fb5546ce1642e280dr1-720-656v2_00.jpg",
"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/52/ed/52/52ed5277222e57504b238f729fe210a5.jpg",
"https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/9b/bd/899bbd8122995b8010f268b30dddf520.jpg",
"https://images3.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED316/5db863834c2e5.jpeg",
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfCZbUixYWzoI2fNq7BYuyqlv0NqpTq7m4ZQ&usqp=CAU",
"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b0/e8/8f/b0e88f383d315a5cdd5df84ae30e4cbd.jpg",
"https://i.redd.it/65w8mczm9my41.jpg",
"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/983107271289815040/GXXiPcA4_400x400.jpg",
"https://enportada.cl/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/69894320_715627375593789_7423265735340653589_n.jpg",
"https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=517x1024:format=jpg/path/s2161fa004f2cb727/image/id1a75c5f4c2019c1/version/1542388804/image.jpg",
"https://enportada.cl/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/75352136_535823540533391_890284238621815372_n.jpg",
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcThoEOzQ6Apae1DloLGH7JMdpzLhwr9KU4BpQ&usqp=CAU",
"https://i.pinimg.com/236x/0b/2e/6f/0b2e6f6fd4dcccd05cb2c607e031ca04.jpg",
"https://img.wattpad.com/cover/192718358-352-k57609.jpg",
"https://images7.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED867/5c7d930d4f412.jpeg",
"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5c/3d/9f/5c3d9f647018a9847f0f05c367fa897a.jpg",
"https://i.redd.it/bn7kk7yrlun51.jpg",
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzq9nRWHG_iz89rh4QXndMHDxi2AlUaK2l7A&usqp=CAU",
"https://cm1.narvii.com/6728/8bd09c9f4f81b5e1059c52977a5a3c9448d66f6b_00.jpg",
"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcShupDbyeRRArGQO5lIPp7_p-1E5eT9_3-t6g&usqp=CAU"];


function addMeme(e){
// "e" es el evento
// e.target es el evento que origino la accion
// previousElementSibling es el elemeno previo en este caso input
//  value es el valor del input
if(e.target.previousElementSibling.value){
    // obtenemos el valor
    // y agregamos al arreglo de imagenes
    memes.push(e.target.previousElementSibling.value);
    // ponemos la imagen como background
    // utilizamos slice para seleccionar la ultima imagen agregada al arreglo
    bodyObj.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + memes.slice(-1) +'")';
}

e.target.previousElementSibling.value="";
}

function updateIndex() {
if (index === (memes.length - 1)) {
    index = 0;
} else {
    ++index;
}
}

function changeElements() {
updateIndex();
bodyObj.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + memes[index] +'")';

}

changeElements();
```

```css
#boton {
    position: absolute;top: 90vh;
}

.imageMeme {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="url" placeholder="URL"> <button onclick="addMeme(event)">addMeme</button>
<body id="body" class="imageMeme">
<button id="boton" onclick="changeElements()">Cambiar Meme</button>
```

Comment: Pero con este método los cambios no se guardarían... cada vez que alguien añada un meme y actualize se borrará por eso quiero el json, para que se guarde cada vez que alguien haga un cambio

Comment: en ese caso necesitarias algun  lenguaje del lado del servidor + una base de datos (sql,nossql,flatfile)  para guardar todos los memes enviados por los usuarios. no se puede solo con html+js

Comment: comprendo... gracias entonces por la respuesta